# Network Printer Batch script

Tags: networking, batch, script, cmd.exe, printer

Fun project right now.

Currently on a network with thousands of printers. I hate when users have to go through the bs windows prompts when trying to map to the printer for the first time. My network doesn't allow vbs so this has to be accomplished by batch.

Quickest way to map right now is "add printer - find printer based on location - location = *building#*room#*" then one result to map. Double click and done.

Would like to be able to run a batch and it asks 
what building is the printer located? Then
What room is the printer located?
Then inputs the variable into searching for the printer

This is what I have so far. Progress but not close yet

@echo off
Set /p loc="Building # where printer is located"
Set /p rm="Room # where printer is located"

Then needs to run a search using *%loc%*%rm%*

I know mapping the printer via cmd line is accomplished through rundll32 printui.dll printuientry, /y /n\ServerName\PrinterName

Need to find the server name & printer name just from location. Anyone have any tips? Thank you for your time

Comment: What do you mean your network doesn't allow VBS.  Your network doesn't know if VBS is using your network or not.  VBS calls standard windows WMI api calls to do its work.  You can disable external WMI, or block WMI packets.  VBS does require administrative rights, so is that what you meant You don't have administrative rights?

Comment: I have admin rights but from the users stand point, they are the ones that are going to be running the script. With zero permissions

Comment: In addition, if you have access to the domain you can use GPO on the network side to force install a given printer based on the user that logs in and probably other criteria.

Comment: No, having the user run a script is completely un-necessary, I have a VBS script which installs the printers remotely without leaving the comfort of my office chair. Any room, building, campus, or etc.  Does this interest you?

Comment: Does interest me out of curiosity. But my issue is the user needs to have this script be dynamic. If they swap buildings / location / room ect I don't want them calling me for remote map. This script will be located in a shared drive and they double click it & enter their info and quick map complete.

Comment: Gpo's aren't an option sadly. That's why batch is my option rn

Comment: Question:  Why are you tying the user to a printer?  I install the printer for the area on all the computer in the area.  Say location A building 4 room 123, the printer in said location installed on all PC in location A building 4 room 123.  If user bob is loc A build 4 room 123 he doesn't want a printer in loc B build 2 room 204 installed as he would have to drive across town to get the print out.  So all pc in room 456 have network printer 456 installed on them.  Doesn't matter who's logged in.

Comment: If bob does drive to loc B build 2 room 123 all computers in said room have the nearest printer installed on it.  Click print, and it comes out the nearest printer.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jXIJheSFXg13Md-_XgmM8PsE-zXOXwZV   I have a public repo of drivers setup you need to look at line 197 and 211 to modify for your needs.  Here's how you use it.  cscript printer.vbs -u AdminUserName -w "Password" -d "HP Universal Printing PS (v6.6.5)" -i hpcu220v.inf -h "\\serverNameOrIP\Path\" -p PrinterName -s ComputerName
The printer name **-d** is found inside the INF specified with **-i**  If you like it I can write it up as answer.

Comment: Would be nice, but wouldn't accomplish what I need. This is what I have now. 

@echo off
set /p loc="Building # where printer is located"
set /p rm="Room # where printer is located"
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n\\*%loc%*%rm%*

the last line. I need it to pull the info \\server\path like it does when you're searching a printer based off location

Comment: errReturn = objPrinter.AddPrinterConnection ("\\PrintServer1\ArtDepartmentPrinter")   We can probably just substitute this command into the script.